# How to get Pending approvals for a particular profile user programmatically?

Tags: apex, visualforce, profile, approval-process

I have two profiles **`Manager`**, **`Agent`**.

If **`Agent`** creates a record in case Object, that will escalate to **`Manager`** profile user for approval.

When **`Manager`** profile user login, I need to display all the case records which are in pending state. Please help to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The object which you are looking for is [ProcessInstanceHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstancehistory.htm).
This read-only object shows all steps and pending approval requests associated with an approval process ([ProcessInstance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstance.htm)).

You can’t query `ProcessInstanceHistory`. Instead, you can query `ProcessInstanceHistory` by including it in a nested query on the parent `ProcessInstance` object. For example, the following SOQL query returns all the `ProcessInstanceHistory` records related to individual `ProcessInstance` records.

The nested query references `StepsAndWorkitems`, which is the child relationshipName for `ProcessInstanceHistory` in the `ProcessInstance` object.

```
SELECT Id, TargetObjectId, (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments FROM StepsAndWorkitems where StepStatus='Pending')
FROM ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId in: caseIds
```

See this thread for more information: [How to Approve the record through Apex Programming.](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008z8VIAQ)

Comment: Thanks for the response.But I want to get the pending records from a particular sObject (In my requirement, it is CASE object).How to identify the records belongs to CASE object?

Comment: i have updated my answer. i think you need to use the `TargetObjectId` field for retrieving only case object records

Comment: TargetObjectId will return ID if the record.But how to verify whether it is belongs to CASE object ?

Comment: Like i did in the query.You need to only retrieve case records.